# Whole text won't show in a table, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I'm trying to is have have table to display my database with an update, delete, and add functions.

My problem is when I view it. It doesn't show the full text in the "Description" column and also in "Developer". Also in the "SecondDirectory" column it shows `</td` instead of just blank if its blank.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("$$$$","$$$$","$$$$");
if (!$con){
die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mydb",$con);


if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$UpdateQuery = "UPDATE table SE ID='$_POST[topic]',Filename='$_POST[filename]', Description='$_POST[description]', TopDirectory='$_POST[topdirectory]', SecondDirectory='$_POST[seconddirectory]', Developer='$_POST[developer]', Date='$_POST[date]' WHERE ID='$_POST[hidden]'";               
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $con);
};

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
$DeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM table WHERE ID='$_POST[hidden]'";          
mysql_query($DeleteQuery, $con);
};

if(isset($_POST['add'])){
$AddQuery = "INSERT INTO table (ID,Filename,Description,TopDirectory,SecondDirectory,Developer,Date) VALUES ('$_POST[uid]','$_POST[ufilename]','$_POST[udescription]','$_POST[utopdirectory]','$_POST[useconddirectory]','$_POST[udeveloper]','$_POST[udate]')";         
mysql_query($AddQuery, $con);
};



$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$myData = mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Filename</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>TopDirectory</th>
<th>SecondDirectory</th>
<th>Developer</th>
<th>Date</th>
</tr>";
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($myData)){
echo "<form action=theworks.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=id value=" . $record['ID'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=filename value=" . $record['Filename'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=description value=" . $record['Description'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=topdirectory value=" . $record['TopDirectory'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=seconddirectory value=" . $record['SecondDirectory'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=developer value=" . $record['Developer'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=date value=" . $record['Date'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $record['ID'] . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=update value=update" . " </td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=delete value=delete" . " </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
}
echo "<form action=database.php method=post>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=uid></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=ufilename></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=udescription><td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=utopdirectory></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=useconddirectory></td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=udeveloper><td>";
echo "<td><input type=text name=udate></td>";
echo "<td>" . "<input type=submit name=add value=add" . " </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you perhaps have quotes in your description?

Comment: Maybe your columns i the database are to short. Mysql will truncate the vlue in this case.

Comment: **Stop** using the deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*`or `PDO` with prepared statements.

Comment: You're not closing any of your input tags in your while loop. You're also needlessly concatenating strings together all over the place when you could just enclose everything within quotes without needlessly breaking out of your strings and concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=description value=" . $record['Description'] . " </td>";
```

What I needed to put is a single quotation right after value= and two single quotations in " " so that it also counts the spaces. The code should have been...

```
echo "<td>" . "<input type=text name=description value='" . $record['Description'] . "'' </td>";
```